# How to create attachment bottom sheet like in the Telegram by jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, attachment, bottom-sheet

How to create attachment bottom sheet like in the Telegram by jetpack compose?
Maybe some examples?

[image]

Comment: Not everybody is going to know what "attachment bottom sheet like in the Telegram" means or looks like. If you click the "Edit" link, you can edit your question to provide more details, including screenshots.

Comment: screenshots attached

Comment: If you need only photos and videos I suggest you look at this photo picker from Google, it is straightforward to use, and there are some limitations but it is quite new and will get improved for sure.
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/photopicker